# How to tell ldapsearch to return non-encrypted values

Tags: oracle, ldap

I am performing ldapsearch to get the users that are member of a specific group.
Unfortunately attributes, such as first name & last name are returned encrypted.

How do I tell ldapsearch to return the values non-encrypted ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and show CODE, logs or results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the values *encrypted* or base 64 encoded? If the attribute looks like:

```
attributeName:: dGVzdCBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
```

With two colons following the attribute name, then you are getting back a base 64 encoded value. You can pipe the output to something that decodes the values

```
| perl -MMIME::Base64 -MEncode=decode -n -00 -e 's/\n +//g;s/(?<=:: )(\S+)/decode("UTF-8",decode_base64($1))/eg;print'
```

Comment: This is exactly the output I get with base64 encoding. The output from ldapsearch is appended on a txt file. Can I somehow use the above proposal in the whole txt file ?